# IBM Cloud - Object storage service name or GUID cannot be found by CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, command-line-interface, object-storage

I'd like to know how I can find my object storage service name or GUID. I executed:

> bx service list

to each resource group. But I cannot get any object storage service name. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 commands:

1) To get the list of all your service instances:

```
$ bx resource service-instances
```

2) To get the ID and other details for a specific service instance:

```
$ bx resource service-instance "<An instance listed from output above>"
```

> Note: Surrounding quotes ("") in step 2 are important as an instance
>   name may contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud object storage deviates from the traditional cloud foundry service model:

> Cloud Object Storage service that was released on our public cloud about a month ago. It’s one of the first services to take advantage of resource groups, giving you some specific advantages as you use it and services like it. You’ll also notice when you deploy an instance of the service, you’re prompted to specify a resource group and a location depending on the plan you selected.
>
> [image]
>
> Source: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/11/organize-navigate-manage-resources-ibm-cloud/

Try using this cli:

```
bluemix resource service-instances
```

Source: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/bx_cli.html#bluemix_cli